# Decorative hanging hooks into plaster and brick wall

Tags: masonry, hanging

I'm at a bit of a loss, but I feel like I can't surely be the only person with this issue. We have a number of keepsake / decorative items that need to be hung by a hook. An example is a surprisingly heavy ceramic wedding horseshoe with a ribbon to hang it.

Because the wall is old plaster and masonry I can't use nails or standard picture hooks. I've looked at normal decorative hooks but they all have small diameter and/or short threads which simply aren't going to screw neatly into any plugs.

So, what on Earth can I use? I'm sure I'm missing a simple and obvious solution. For hanging pictures I've been drilling a hole into the mortar, adding a plug and then fixing a screw to hang in the picture. This works fine where you can't see anything, but I'm looking for a more attractive solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are extra sharp, [thin nails](http://www.homedepot.com/p/OOK-Blue-Steel-Pro-Nails-Tidy-Tins-25-Piece-50614/202341384) used in several brands of picture hangers that reduce the chance of cracking or chipping plaster
[image: ook nail]
They also can be used alone if the item is not too heavy.

You also could use an anchor and a flat head screw and then merely glue a decorative button or other item from a craft store to the head.

> Images and links are for illustration only, not an endorsement of goods or sources.

Comment: I have had great luck with those on sheetrock but would worry about plaster cracking. They do have nice brass hangers and some take 3? Of those pins if I remember correctly for heavy items.